# Trying to use stored procedure to access three tables but receiving only one row

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

So far I have tried many different ways of accessing the data on three tables using a stored procedure. First I tried a simple select statement :

```
create procedure reportCodes () begin
SELECT Numbers.serial_numb, numOwner.lName, numOwner.fName, numOwner.email,
 location.long, location.lat, Numbers.dateValidated
FROM Numbers, Owner, location
WHERE Numbers.used = true AND Numbers.id=numOwner.Numbers_id AND     
 Numbers.id=location.Numbers_id; 
end$$
```

(names changed to protect the guilty)

Running the stored procedure in phpmyadmin results in the first instance of the record (1 out of two ‘true’ in the test database).  Running just:

```
SELECT Numbers.serial_numb, numOwner.lName, numOwner.fName, numOwner.email,  
 location.long, location.lat, Numbers.dateValidated
FROM Numbers, Owner, location
WHERE Numbers.used = true AND Numbers.id=numOwner.Numbers_id AND 
Numbers.id=location.Numbers_id;
```

in the phpmyadmin SQL tab returns both records. Then I tried a temp table:

```
create procedure reportCodes () begin
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE used_numbers AS (
SELECT Numbers.serial_numb, numOwner.lName, numOwner.fName, numOwner.email,
 location.long, location.lat, Numbers.dateValidated
FROM Numbers, Owner, location
WHERE Numbers.used = true AND Numbers.id=numOwner.Numbers_id AND 
 Numbers.id=location.Numbers_id);

SELECT * FROM used_numbers; end$$
```

Returns 1 of 2 records as the procedure but both records in console. Finally I tried changing my table to a join:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE reportCodes()
begin
create temporary table used_numbers AS (
SELECT Numbers.serial_numb, numOwner.lName, numOwner.fName, numOwner.email,
 location.long, location.lat, Numbers.dateValidated
FROM Numbers JOIN numOwner
ON Numbers.id=numOwner.Numbers_id 
JOIN location ON
 numOwner.Numbers_id=location.Numbers_id
WHERE Numbers.used = true
);

SELECT * FROM used_numbers; end$$
```

Same results as above. I’m at a loss as to why running just the SQL would show both test records but running the procedure with the exact same code only yields one.
Thanks

Comment: Why do not you give the structure of your table and some temporary data, so that we can atleast try where is the problem?

Comment: I'm interested to know if this was solved? If not, did SHOW WARNINGS give any information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your query, numOwners isn't a valid table being selected against, so something's wrong.  Have you tried running your SQL in the Query window in phpMyAdmin to ensure that the EXACT same query is returning 2 rows?

I presume the "Owner" table is supposed to be "numOwner", so I've re-written the stored procedure call below.  Also, I'm not sure what types of values you're storing in Numbers.used to evaluate to "TRUE".  I will presume you're using a TINYINT(1), so I've altered that, as well.  I hope this helps.

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `db`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `reportCodes`$$

CREATE PROCEDURE `reportCodes`()
BEGIN
  SELECT 
    n.serial_numb, 
    o.lName, 
    o.fName, 
    o.email,  
    l.long, 
    l.lat, 
    n.dateValidated
  FROM Numbers n
  INNER JOIN numOwner o ON n.id=o.Numbers_id 
  INNER JOIN location l ON n.id=l.Numbers_id; 
  WHERE n.used = 1
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```